# Oracle GroupBy of worlds from text field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of

```
Full Name - varchar2(200)
Age - Number
```

can I get the count of name for example that inside the textfield

and I dont mean to `Select Count(*) from table;`

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post some sample data and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the requirements but I guess this is what you want

```
select count(*), name from table group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the "textfield"? A bind variable? A value in a column in a different table? The standard solution is

```
select count(*) from <your_table_name> where <textfield> like '%' || "First Name" || '%' ;
```

I used double-quotes around First Name - that is the only way column names in Oracle may contain spaces (but I hope you didn't actually do that, it is a very poor practice). Also, if there is the risk that "Jackson" appears in the textfield and you don't want that to count as "Jack" (first name), then replace the last `'%'` with `' %'` (single-quote, SPACE, %, single-quote).

This will give the total number of names from your table that are present in the text field. It will not count duplicates (if `John` appears five times, it will still be only counted once). If this is not your requirement, please state your requirement more clearly. For example, you may instead want to show how many times each of the names in your table appears in the textfield... or any number of other possible interpretations. What do you really need?